# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get the TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in python 2.7.5 when executing the following code:

```
range=5
res=0.1
hklmax = int(range/res)
x=0
for h in range(-hklmax,hklmax):
    x+=h
```

If I simply put the range of h in directly rather than as a variable I do not get the error. I imagine it is something very obvious but I'm an absolute beginner to python and don't understand the error.

Answer (score 6):

You are making a mistake right here:

```
range=5
```

You are changing the `range` function into an integer.  Try changing range to something else that isn't a keyword like `rng` everywhere in the script and things will be fine.

Don't change this line though:

```
for h in range(-hklmax,hklmax):
```

That's where you're actually wanting to use the keyword.